# Multiple errors in .NET Core 5 mvc result in `Exception in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, error-handling

I was implementing/testing my error handling in my new .NET 5 MVC project and I came across the following.

1. Throw error in HomeController

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
        return View();
    }
```

2. Exception gets handled in ErrorController by the app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var vm = new ErrorViewModel();
            var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
```

3. By now the following gets executed in _Layout

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
```

4. Menu contains also an error

```
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            throw new Exception("xxx");
```

Now I would expect that the last error would again go through my ErrorController but I just get a blank page with a 500 message. No error in the code, it just stops there.

Tried looking in de Debug output but all I could find was:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

When I throw the 2 errors separate everything works, but when the 2 come together it fails. It's like .NET can't handle multiple errors at once.

When I use app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); it just stops at the first exception which is great but when I try to simulate 'production' it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Debug/Windows/Exception Settings and check exception under Common Language Runtime Exceptions. The debugger will stop when the exception is thrown and you will be able to see what is going on.

Note that it is not unusual for exceptions to be expected and handled in some cases. You may find that the exception is expected and handled, and nothing needs to be done to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you suggested but it just stops in my _layout at this line

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
```

And when I view the error, well, it's the one I threw at step 4. Which all makes sense up untill that point.

But then I was expecting the program would hop back into my error controller so I can properly catch it and show my error page.

All it does now is give a page like this:

[example of my 500 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U36Ce.png)